# How to move a div's scrollers to the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I have a div with with the following css:

```
.long-table-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Instead of attaching scrollbars to `.long-table-container`, I would like to instead use the browser's scrollbars to do the job. Is this possible?

The reason I need to do this is because I have a long table in `.long-table-container` and the only way to scroll left and right is by scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page and then moving horizontal scroller of `.long-table-container` which is a pain for any user.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ox5qzp1x/

Comment: you could try to add overflow-y:hidden property so that the vertical scroll doesn't show, though its not very clear what you're trying to do, why don't you do a fiddle so it's clearer (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: jsfiddle needed cant tell what you actually need...

Comment: what happens if you remove that line from the CSS? the content should overflow and the browser scrollbar should appear instead

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional scrollable element with fixed position at bottom of the page and connect these two elements, like in question [*Attach Horizontal Scrollbar to bottom of window if scrollable div is taller than window*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812919/attach-horizontal-scrollbar-to-bottom-of-window-if-scrollable-div-is-taller-than/24818445#24818445)