# Scroll bar manipulation

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

is any chance to have a scroll bar element that I can move where I want on the page but to link with my scroll box? I have created my scroll box ready but I need a scroll bar that should to be moved on other place on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - look at [Advanced Scrollbars Demo page](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/advanced.html) - *External* scrollbar.

If you want to use native browser scrollbar (or do not like custom scrollbars), you will have to use two containers - one with your scrollable content and the second one - with scrollbar that attached to first container. Look at question [Attach Horizontal Scrollbar to bottom of window if scrollable div is taller than window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812919/attach-horizontal-scrollbar-to-bottom-of-window-if-scrollable-div-is-taller-than/24818445#24818445)