# How can I create a sticky horizontal scrollbar for a div with content taller than the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a div with no scrollbars vertically, but scroll bars if needed horizontally, which are sticky with respect to the viewport. I don't want to the user to have to scroll to the bottom of the page to scroll horizontally.

GitHub does this for any file such as [CREDITS](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/CREDITS).

[image: middle of the viewport]

Bottom of the viewport:

[image: bottom of the viewport]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812919/attach-horizontal-scrollbar-to-bottom-of-window-if-scrollable-div-is-taller-than) look promising, but I have no jQuery.

**Update**

This is the best I've got so far, but it *always* shows a scrollbar which is the behavior GitHub has.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sticky Scrollbar Example</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .container {
        position: relative;        
        width: calc(100vw - 88px);
        margin: 40px;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      .content {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* Hiding the real scrollbar */
        scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
      }
      .content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none; /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      }
      .scrollbar-container {
        position: sticky;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height: 17px;
      }
      .scrollbar {
        height: 1px;
        width: 200%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <!-- Add enough text to overflow horizontally -->
        <!-- Repeat the line multiple times to overflow vertically -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>
        <!-- Add more lines as needed -->
      </div>
      <div class="scrollbar-container">
        <div class="scrollbar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const contentDiv = document.querySelector(".content");
        const scrollbarContainer = document.querySelector(".scrollbar-container");

        scrollbarContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
          contentDiv.scrollLeft = scrollbarContainer.scrollLeft; /* Move the invisible real scrollbar */
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make the height of the section/div to 100vh or lesser than viewport height. a simple ugly eg:

```css
div{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>lorem2 sadfjkha sdf lsakdhf askljd fhaskdjfh asdlkjf h asdjkfh askd fhsdfkjhas dfkljasd fhkljsad fhlakshdfalwuehf awkjfh ksljdcbnlkasfbh lskjbdcl askjbc laksjdcb slakjdcb aslkdjbc aslkjdcbkaslbdcl kasjd lksadbclkasjbc sakljb</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: scroll` will make the scrollbar always appear, I want the horizontal scroll bar to appear when needed (window is shrunk) and be sticky to the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution that involves the following hacks:

1. Hiding the native scrollbar with css
2. Using JS to sync a fake sticky scrollbar with the real one
3. Watching for window resizes and adjusting the scrollbar as needed

Note: Only problem is that mobile safari is displaying no scroll bar at all.

**Update**

Code updated, native touch horizontal scrollbars remain visible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sticky Scrollbar Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: calc(100vw - 88px);
      margin: 40px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Hiding the real scrollbar */
      scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
      -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
    }
    .hide-native-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }    
    .sticky-scrollbar-container {
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      height: 0;
    }
    .stick-scrollbar {
      height: 1px;
      width: 200%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content hide-native-scrollbar">
      Content added by JS for brevity.<br>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-scrollbar-container">
      <div class="sticky-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const content = document.querySelector(".content");
      const scrollbarContainer = document.querySelector(".sticky-scrollbar-container");
      const scrollbar = document.querySelector(".sticky-scrollbar")
      const isTouchDevice = navigator.maxTouchPoints || 'ontouchstart' in document;

      content.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        content.innerHTML += "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum longe vero, dolorem, iusto dolorum<br>";
      }

      if (isTouchDevice) {
        content.classList.remove("hide-native-scrollbar");
      }

      scrollbar.style.width = content.scrollWidth + "px";

      if (content.scrollWidth > content.clientWidth && !isTouchDevice) {
        scrollbarContainer.style.height = "17px";
      } else {
        scrollbarContainer.style.height = "0";
      }

      scrollbarContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        content.scrollLeft = scrollbarContainer.scrollLeft;
      });

      content.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        scrollbarContainer.scrollLeft = content.scrollLeft;
      });

      window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        scrollbar.style.width = content.scrollWidth + "px";
        if (content.scrollWidth > content.clientWidth && !isTouchDevice) {
          scrollbarContainer.style.height = "17px";
        } else {
          scrollbarContainer.style.height = "0";
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```